# Error: "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I am setting up visual studio code for unity. I tried to install `c#` extension but the error

```
The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path
```

keeps popping up. All I want is to enable `IntelliSense` because its not working.

I already tried the ff:
reinstall the `SDK` after closing an open visual studio code
restart the computer
I also tried to make sure that `C:\Program File\dotnet` is on the path under system variable

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows

Comment: Make sure you didn't mess up the bitness, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk-due-to-bitness

Answer (score -1):

First install vscode extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp

If you got error like this "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path" then install https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.300-windows-x64-installer

If vscode shows "The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found" on output terminal then install developer pack https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net471 then try exit and open vs code if not work then restart